# TypeScript 2: Using Namespaces without reference Triple-Slash Directive

Tags: reactjs, typescript, namespaces, typescript2.0

I have a TypeScript React Project, where I am currently using the Module import for every single file I have.
In this Project I have a 'Container' Component, which contains multiple 'Content' Components.
Currently the Container imports the Content like this:

```
import {Content} from "./Content";
```

Now I want to change my project to the TypeScript Namespaces, so I don't have to specify the relative Path of every single file I'm using.

I already specified my tsconfig.json to include every file in my project folder:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "locale": "en-us",
    "outFile": "./dist/bundle.js"
}
}
```

The src folder contains all my typescript classes.

Now I have rewritten my files like this:

Content.tsx:

```
namespace ContainerSpace {
    export class Content extends React.Component<any, any> {
    ...
    }
}
```

Container.tsx:

```
import Content = ContainerSpace.Content;

namespace ContainerSpace {
    export class Container extends React.Component<any, any> {
    ...
    render() {
        return <Content/>
    }
    ...
}
```

But when I compile I get an error like this:

```
error TS2339: Property 'Content' does not exist on type 'typeof ContainerSpace'.
```

**How do I use Namespaces in multiple files, without having to use the Reference directive?** I've read that it is possible using the tsconfig.json, but never actually found someone explaining how to configure the tsconfig, so I don't have to use the reference comments.

Comment: I think you just can't...